# What type of Aloe is this ? Do the properties differ much?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care, aloe

lately I came across this Aloe that looked a bit like a different type, it has white marks and spiky sides generally looks like normal medical aloe properties but cannot really tell since i first time encountered with one looking like this, maybe will look more familiar when it grows ? the leaves are not 40cm long yet but almost around there... Thank you, will be waiting for answers...

[image]

Comment: Gently check how sharp the spikes are.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler , soft spikes